# Data is not rethrew in my react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have created a simple react native application with fire base and the data rethrew is not working. when run the application data are visible on the console, but data cannot view on the mobile screen. Please help me to solve this issue,

This is my `App.js` file

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, TextInput } from "react-native";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import ShoppingItems from "./components/ShoppingItems";
import {app,db,getFirestore,collection,addDoc,getDocs,} from "./firebase/index";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState([]);

  const addShopingItem = async () => {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "shopping"), {
        title: title,
        isCheked: false,
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
      setTitle("");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
  };

  const getShoppingItems = async () => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "shopping"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
      setShoppingList({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getShoppingItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        {/* header */}
        <Text style={styles.heading}>Sghopping Items</Text>
        {/* noofshoppng items */}
        <Text style={styles.noOfItems}>2</Text>
        {/* delete button */}
        <Pressable>
          <MaterialIcons
            style={styles.deleteIcon}
            name="delete"
            size={30}
            color="black"
          />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      {/* flat List */}
      {shoppingList.length > 0 ? (
        <FlatList
          data={shoppingList}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <ShoppingItems title={item.title} />}
          keyExtrator={(item) => item.id}
        />
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      )}

      {/* Text inpus */}
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Enter Shoping Itms"
        value={title}
        onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)}
        onSubmitEditing={addShopingItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

This is my `ShppingItems.js` file

```
    import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
    import React from "react";
    import { AntDesign, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
    import { Pressable } from "react-native";
    
    const ShoppingItems = (props) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Pressable>
            <AntDesign name="checkcircleo" size={24} color="black" />
          </Pressable>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    };

export default ShoppingItems;
```

this is the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBnMN.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatlist receives an array as data.

```
<FlatList
  data={[{title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1'}]}
  ...
>
```

data: For simplicity, data is a plain array. If you want to use something else, like an immutable list, use the underlying VirtualizedList directly. [Source: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist]

You are feeding it with an object instead of an array:

```
setShoppingList({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      });
```

The correct code should be:

```
const getShoppingItems = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "shopping"));
  const newShoppingList = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
    newShoppingList.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    });
  });
  setShoppingList(newShoppingList);
};
```